# Do C++ standard library algorithms use std::advance

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, iterator, language-lawyer

I have not been able to find a decent source for this.  Do all algorithms in the `<algorithm>` header use `std::advance` to increment (and possibly decrement) iterators?

Also another related follow up - I saw the cppreference page for the RandomAccessIterator concept (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) , but it did not address the requirement for having member alias for an iterator category.  If an iterator class does not have a member typedef named `iterator_category` that is aliased to `random_access_iterator_tag` but supports the operations that are mentioned in the cppreference page (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) for RandomAccessIterator, does the c++ standard library assume that the iterator is a random access iterator?

**Note** I meant to ask this question with reference to the C++ standard.  i.e. "What does the standard say about this?"

Comment: I can't think of any algorithm that would need to advance an iterator by more than 1. The algorithms that come to mind would typically increment or decrement the iterators, and so are far more likely to use only `++` and `--`. Perhaps with the exception of sort, and shuffle. But, in any case, the answer can be easily determined by searching through the header file itself. You should be able to figure this out by yourself.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I asked this question looking for a possible quote from the standard.  Looking at the implementation is not sufficient because that can change while still maintaining the standard.  Also `std::upper_bound` and `std::lower_bound` which are frequently used use `std::advance` in most implementations to advance an iterator by `n` steps

Comment: I've searched through the entire section 25, "Algorithms library". There's only one mention of `advance()` in it, at the very beginning, but only very loosely, specifying that any reference to `a+n`, in this section's specification, when applied to non-random access iterators means "as if" `advance()` was used. I'm not prepared to argue that this actually requires `advance()`. It states only "as if" advance() is used. It clearly doesn't *prohibit* `advance()`, but doesn't require it, IMO. I'm going to add the `language-lawyer` tag to this.

Comment: The standard describes constraints (e.g. that the number of operations is O(1) or O(n), the result is the same *as if* something was done) on working of standard algorithms, rather than mandating how the algorithms are implemented.

Comment: ... this question already has 5 tags. I leave it up to you if you want to drop one of them and replace it with "language-lawyer".

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Added that tag.  Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Note that using advance instead of  `[]` may result in algorithms that require random access iterators to accidentally accept bidirectional iterators resulting in code that compiles and yields correct results, but performs terribly. (at least pre-concepts)

Comment: @Peter I was just wondering what implementation of an iterator tag would qualify it as a "RandomAccessIterator" and make the implementations pick advancing the iterator by `n` instead of incrementally by one

Comment: When an iterator is declared, it must specify, as its trait, what kind of an iterator it is. It follows that an iterator that meets all requirements for a random access iterator will declare itself as such. If you want to know the actual requirements for a random access iterator, see Google. Plenty of reference stuff on the web.

Comment: @Curious I don't know exactly the reason you are interested in knowing that, but if `std::avance` receives random access iterators, the complexity is constant, like doing `v[i]`, so, `std::advance` is so fast as it could be by other means. What's is wrong with using `std::advance`?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I understand, I was wondering whether having a `iterator_category` set to `random_access_iterator_tag` would be sufficient for all implementations to pick the random increment

Comment: @Peregring-lk nothing at all.  I was making an iterator class and was trying to figure out what makes it sufficient for standard library algorithms to use the advance by `n` version instead of manually incrementing `n` times.

Comment: @Curious - The capabilities specific to a random access iterator are not limited to advancing.   From memory (i.e. check to be sure) a random access iterator supports all operations of bidirectional iterator plus a few more, where the "few more" include advancing by `n`, comparison with inequality operators, and offset dereference (`[]`).   Algorithms that require a random access iterator would be permitted but (probably) not required to use those.

Comment: @Curious "the library introduces category tag classes which are used as compile time tags for algorithm selection.". I'd say inheriting your iterator from `iterator<...>` or specializing `iterator_traits` for it is sufficient

Comment: As far as GCC is concerned it uses ++ when scanning and advance when jumping (stl_algo.h).

Answer (score 2):

The standard does not specify the implementation of C++ `std` algorithms explicitly.  It specifies behavior, and sometimes how many times particular operations are done.  This can leave the implementer with little practical choice, but it is not explicitly specified.

`std::advance` is never called out in the standard as being called by another algorithm to the best of my knowledge.  Which means it could be used, or not used, in a particular implementation of a particular algorithm.

The effects of `std::advance` are specified.  Insofar as other algorithms specify their operation counts, in order to call `std::advance` it must not break their guarantees.

In short, using it is permitted and not required.